# Repeat a function 5 times with for on JavaScript

Tags: javascript, function, loops, for-loop

I'm trying to repeat a function 5 times, with different inputs. The thing is, the function works OK outside of the for loop, but inside of it it will only work 1 time.
Here is my code:

```
    var string;
var num;
function comandos(string, num){

    let resultado = "";

    for (i=0; i<string.length; i++){

        if (string.charAt(i) == "i"){
            num = num + 1;
        }else if (string.charAt(i) == "d"){
            num = num - 1;
        }else if (string.charAt(i) == "c"){
            num = Math.pow(num, 2);
        }else if (string.charAt(i) == "p"){
            resultado = resultado + "*" + num + "*";
        }
    }

return resultado;

}

for (i=0; i<5; i++){
    string = prompt("Ingrese secuencia de comandos (i, d, c, p)").toLowerCase();
    num = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese número"));
    console.log(comandos(string, num));
    console.log("prueba")
}
```

Edit: I just realize I have a lot of code on Spanish, let me know if you guys need a translation.

Comment: When you say it will only work one time, do you mean it runs all five times but gives the same result each time or that the loop only runs once?

Comment: The loop only runs once, both prompts only prompt once and the function only runs once. The las console.log("prueba") is a test, it only runs once but if I remove all the rest of the code on the for it does runs 5 times.

Comment: let i=0 instead of i=0

Comment: Gotcha. Is there ever a time where the string parameter to comandos will be more than one character long?

Comment: Yes, the string is almost always more than one character long, but the issue was that I had to define the variable i on the for loop as the other guys said. Thanks to all of you guys!

Comment: Sure thing—was just thinking you could eliminate that for loop entirely otherwise :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has to do with the scope of the variable `i`. Since you didn't declare the variable like so: `var i = 0` or `let i = 0`, javascript will treat it as a global var. That means `i` in the function `commandos` is the same variable as `i` in the outer for loop. So the loop in `comandos` will increase the value of `i`, causing the outer for loop to exit early.

```js
var string;
var num;

function comandos(string, num) {

  let resultado = "";

  for (let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {

    if (string.charAt(i) == "i") {
      num = num + 1;
    } else if (string.charAt(i) == "d") {
      num = num - 1;
    } else if (string.charAt(i) == "c") {
      num = Math.pow(num, 2);
    } else if (string.charAt(i) == "p") {
      resultado = resultado + "*" + num + "*";
    }
  }

  return resultado;

}

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  string = prompt("Ingrese secuencia de comandos (i, d, c, p)").toLowerCase();
  num = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese número"));
  console.log(comandos(string, num));
  console.log("prueba")
}
```